# Jacoco not showing Spock code coverage in my Gradle project

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, code-coverage, spock, jacoco

I have a Gradle project configured with jacoco plugin to report the test code coverage. My unit tests are written in Spock framework.

Though the Jacoco plugin generates the HTML report, it reports the code coverage as 0% on all classes.

I googled a lot and couldn't find what I'm missing. Has anyone got the Spock code coverage working with Gradle + Jacoco?

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "groovy"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
        groovy {srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy'] }
        resources { srcDir 'src/main/resources' }
    }

    test {
        java { srcDirs = ['src/test/java'] }
        groovy { srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy'] }
        resources { srcDir 'src/test/resources' }
    }
}

test {
    jvmArgs '-Xms64m', '-Xmx2G', '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:0.7-groovy-2.0"
}
```

Comment: Getting code coverage to work with Spock is no different to getting it to work with JUnit. Adding Groovy source dirs to `sourceSets.main.java` and `sourceSets.test.java` doesn't seem right. Also the `doFirst` doesn't seem right. Things like `classDumpFile` shouldn't have to be configured manually (unless you aren't happy with the defaults). Perhaps start from one of the JaCoCo sample builds in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Thanks @PeterNiederwieser. I fixed the `sourceSets.main.java` and `sourceSets.test.java`, and removed `classDumpFile`. However I am not clear what is wrong with `doFirst{}`. Any clues?

Comment: There is no reason to wrap configuration of `classDirectories` with `doFirst`. I wasn't talking about `classDumpFile` in particular. Just saying that the more defaults are changed, the higher the chance of going wrong somewhere. Again, check the samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: I have removed the configurations overriding defaults. I have a plain-vanilla configuration now. Still the coverage is reported as 0%. I downloaded the latest full Gradle distribution looking for examples, but none of the samples have Jacoco configured in them.

Comment: I take my above comment back on Gradle sample. In fact there is a example under /samples/testing/jacoco. I have the exact same configuration in my project. The only difference is, my sources are in Java, tests are in Spock. I'm totally out of clues here.

Comment: Perhaps check the `--debug` log. The whole `sourceSets` block can be removed as it's just reiterating the defaults.

Comment: I just tried with a basic example (one Java production class, one Spock test class) and it worked just fine. I recommend to start with the simplest possible build that just applies the `groovy` and `jacoco` plugins (without any further configuration), configures `jacocoTestReport` to generate an HTML report, and adds the necessary repository and dependencies. Note that you'll have to run `gradle test jacocoReport`, not just `gradle jacocoReport`.

Comment: Also make sure to try with a recent Gradle version (I used 1.12).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @PeterNiederwieser. I will try your suggestions. At work, we are using 1.11 as standard. Don't know if I can upgrade to 1.12 now.

Comment: Also works fine in 1.11 for me.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way you could share the example you tried? I can take it from there and start debugging. Thanks again for all your efforts.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pniederw/7f848626f6386d18e1b5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggestion from @PeterNiederwieser worked perfectly. Here is the final result:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
  compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.2"
  testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to drill down to line coverage in the source code? In my reports, the method names are not clickable, so I can't get down to the lines in the source. I use Spock 1.0, Gradle 2.8 and Groovy 2.4.